# How do I add a selector or function delegate as a member of a struct?

Tags: ios, swift

For each item in a list of `Item` I want to specify a function member like `let function: ???` where its type will allow me to assign a function like `open(Item)`

```
struct Item {
    let label: String
    let roomID: Int
    let function: ??? <- what can I say here that takes a function like open(Item)
}
```

EDIT: Here I'm trying the `(Item) -> Void`. But I'm getting this error: `'(MyClass) -> (MyClass.Item) -> Void' is not convertible to '(MyClass.Item) -> Void'`

```
let tabTwoItems = [
    Item(label: "Label", id: 1234, image: "image", function: tabTwoFunction)
]

struct Item {
    let label: String
    let id: Int
    let image: String
    let function: (Item) -> Void
}

func tabTwoFunction(_ item: Item) -> Void {

}
```

Comment: `(input: String) -> (String)` this will make it a function that takes a string and returns a string.

Comment: `let function: (Item) -> Void`?

Comment: Is there supposed to be something else after `Item(label: "Label", id: 1234, image:`?

Comment: I updated my question: these methods are not working

Comment: You missed a bit of the init method in your code. How are you setting the function?

Comment: Did you make a typo copying what Fabio Felici said? It's `let function: (Item) -> Void`, not `let function: (item: Item) -> Void`

Comment: Please just add all of your code. You have not included `MyClass` in any of your question. Just add all the problem code, not little snippets of it.

Comment: Your problem is that tabTwoFunction is an instance function. It needs to be a static function. Or you need to pass an instance into it.

Comment: @Fogmeister just create a swift playground or a class- thats all you need

Comment: @Fogmeister is there a way to make it an instance function?

Comment: @visc you need a static function. Just add `static` before `func`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct Item {
    let label: String
    let roomID: Int
    let function: (Item) -> Void
}
```

but more efficient is using protocols:

```
protocol ItemDelegate {
    func call(item: Item)
}

struct Item {
    let label: String
    let roomID: Int
    let itemDelegate: ItemDelegate
}
```

The second solution may lay in the stack. It has more performance.

For global methods use enum namespaces:

The problem in your playground that tabTwoFunction is declared too late. In order to fix it, wrap it my namespace:

```
enum NameSpace {

static func tabTwoFunction(_ item: Item) -> Void {

}

static let tabTwoItems = [
    NameSpace.Item(label: "Label", id: 1234, image: "image", function: tabTwoFunction)
]

struct Item {
    let label: String
    let id: Int
    let image: String
    let function: (Item) -> Void
}
}
```